# JUnit and checking fields for null

Tags: java, junit, constructor, default-constructor

When I test the default cons. in a class like this:

```
public class Man {
    public Man(){}

@Test
public void defConstructorTest() {
    Man m = new Man();
    assertEquals(0, m.getName());
    assertEquals(0, m.getBorn());
```

comes the message:

`test failed expected: 0 but was: null`

When I change the code like this:

```
@Test
public void defConstructorTest() {
    Man m = new Man();
    assertEquals(null, m.getName());
    assertEquals(null, m.getBorn());
```

test failed again with this message is shown:

`expected: null but was: 0`

Can somebody explain why am I getting this error? (Getters are working fine)

Comment: Could you please post complete code here ? Where does e defined ?

Comment: I assume that `name` is not a number (or is not a primitive), but `born` is a primitive.

Comment: Is it actually meaningful to create a `Man` with null name and zero... bornness? As in: does it make sense to have a default constructor at all?

Comment: the sense to understand testing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shared enough code of `Man` to give a definite answer, but from the error messages (and some common sense) I'd guess that `getName()` returns a `String` and `getBorn()` returns an `int` with the year the man was born on. Assuming these are just simple getters that return data members, the default for a `String` (or any other object, for that matter) is `null` unless it's explicitly initialized, and the default for a primitive `int` is `0`.

To make a long story short, you need to expect the right default value for each getter:

```
@Test
public void defConstructorTest() {
    Man m = new Man();
    assertNull(m.getName());
    assertEquals(0, m.getBorn());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to assert null value, you should use

```
assertNull()
```

Also, you assign "new Man()" to "m" variable, but in asserts you use "e" variable.

Comment: `assertNull` is merely a convenience method, which can give a more meaningful failure message. Not using it does not explain why the test fails.